# Change radio button text inside <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am searching for a different way to change the word `FOO` with javascript:

```
<div class="radio"">
  <label for="radios-1" id="lbl_radio-1" class="unchecked_radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="1">
    <span>FOO</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I came up with the solution

```
var v = document.getElementById('lbl_radio-1');
v.innerHTML=v.innerHTML.replace("<span>FOO</span>","<span>BAR</span>");
```

But I find it is not the right way. There must be something better, shorter, nicer...

Check this out: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zpk7aw3/1/)

Is there a way to directly address the `radios-1` id? At least I did not succeed. And why can't I show the `innerHTML` for the latter, but for the former `lbl_radio-1`?

Comment: Is the `<span>` there for presentation, or just to easily target/change the text?

Comment: I wanted a boxy look that detects hover, like in the fiddle. This was a solution I found. If I could get away without the span, even better.

Comment: Depending on what sort of 'hover' effects you wanted you could possibly do without it (but it's dependant on what you need/want to do); I was just wondering if it was for the JavaScript text-changing; because it's easy [with](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/47ackk2n/) or [without](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/47ackk2n/1/) the `<span>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to target the span that follows the radio button.

You can then set its text content directly:

```
var v = document.querySelector('#radios-1 + span');
v.textContent= 'BAR';
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hLzedL8u/)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using jquery you could use :

```
$('#radios-1').next().text('BAR');
//OR
$('#radios-1').next('span').text('BAR');
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$('#radios-1').next().text('BAR');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label for="radios-1" id="lbl_radio-1" class="unchecked_radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="1"/>
    <span>FOO</span>
  </label>
</div>
```